# How does imbibition and turgor pressure generate much force?

Tags: osmosis

Both imbibition and turgor pressure together create a large force in plants such as force required to burst the seed coat open?

Comment: Please answer this question

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and either delete or [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, we encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). Thanks! 